# Is there a way to order the lines which a git diff shows changes?

Tags: git, github

So say I do a git diff where I'm editing multiple lines in the same area, and I get:

```
-   Change 1
+   Change1
-   Change 2
+   Change2
```

Can I change the order which the diffs show up to be something like this:

```
-   Change 1
-   Change 2
+   Change1
+   Change2
```

This way I could more easily show what changes I've made if someone decides to diff my commit with the previous one on github.

Answer (score 4):

The *order* of `git diff` output is determined by the order of the source lines, since it works sequentially.  So the answer to the question in the *subject line* of this SO posting ("is there a way to [re]order the lines") is simply "no".

But that seems not to be the question you *intended*, based on your example.  (Good thing you provided an example!)

Let's take a look at some actual `git diff` output, and how [these two command line argument control knobs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) affect it:

> `-Un`, `--unified=n`
>
> Generate diffs with *n* lines of context instead of the usual three. Implies `-p`.
>
> `--inter-hunk-context=lines`
>
> Show the context between diff hunks, up to the specified number of lines, thereby fusing hunks that are close to each other.

I made a repository with just a `README` file and then made two changes to it.  The first change is on line 1 and the second is on line 9.  Here is the standard `git diff` output:

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/README b/README
index 441ad85..0e6fd7d 100644
--- a/README
+++ b/README
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-This is a README file
+This is a README file MOD1
 which I am using just
 for showing some
 cases of using
@@ -6,4 +6,4 @@ git diff with
 flags to adjust
 the amount of
 context that will
-be shown.
+be shown. MOD2
```

Let's use `-U` to decrease the amount of context from three lines to just one:

```
$ git diff -U1
diff --git a/README b/README
index 441ad85..0e6fd7d 100644
--- a/README
+++ b/README
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
-This is a README file
+This is a README file MOD1
 which I am using just
@@ -8,2 +8,2 @@ the amount of
 context that will
-be shown.
+be shown. MOD2
```

The diff is *shorter*, but still has some context.  (Incidentally, note that there's no "above" context for `MOD1` and no "below" context for `MOD2` because the file has no lines above or below this point.  Normally both `git diff` outputs would be somewhat longer, if the file had more text in it.  We would have three lines of context above line 1, and 3 more lines below line 9, in the first diff, if those were available.  We would have 1 line above line 1, and 1 line below line 9, in the second.)

Increasing the lines-of-context has the side effect of fusing the diffs:

```
$ git diff -U4
diff --git a/README b/README
index 441ad85..0e6fd7d 100644
--- a/README
+++ b/README
@@ -1,9 +1,9 @@
-This is a README file
+This is a README file MOD1
 which I am using just
 for showing some
 cases of using
 git diff with
 flags to adjust
 the amount of
 context that will
-be shown.
+be shown. MOD2
```

This is because, with 4 lines of context below the change on line 1, the diff hunk shows lines 1 through 5 inclusive; with 4 lines of context above the change on line 9; the diff hunk shows lines 5 through 9 inclusive.  Line 5 and line 5 are the same, so the two hunks get fused.

Or, even when using `-U1` or the somewhat crazy `-U0` (no context at all), I can use `--inter-hunk-context` to add *additional* context *between* the first and second diff hunk, up to the point where they join.  With `-U1`, I need `--inter-hunk-context=5` to get any effect.

```
$ git diff -U1 --inter-hunk-context=5
diff --git a/README b/README
index 441ad85..0e6fd7d 100644
--- a/README
+++ b/README
@@ -1,9 +1,9 @@
-This is a README file
+This is a README file MOD1
 which I am using just
 for showing some
 cases of using
 git diff with
 flags to adjust
 the amount of
 context that will
-be shown.
+be shown. MOD2
```

This time, the first hunk shows lines 1 through 2, and the second shows lines 8 through 9.  We add 5 more lines—which are lines 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7—and now the two hunks adjoin and become fused into one diff hunk.

Using `-U0`, we need `--inter-hunk-context=7`, as the base diff hunks are only for line 1 and line 9, and we must add lines 2 through 8 (7 lines) to cause them to join.

There's one more relevant option you may use:

> `-W`, `--function-context`
>
> Show whole surrounding functions of changes.

**For this particular `README` file**, which contains plain-text English, this option is not useful, as there are no "functions" in such a file.  Whether `-W` works depends on the file's language, and whether Git can recognize functions written in that language.